# I got this error when I tried to convert ionic to apk

Tags: ionic-framework

> (node:10556) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to
>   find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
>   Detected 'adb' command at C:\Android but no 'platform-tools' directory
>   found near. Try reinstall Android SDK or update your PATH to include
>   valid path to SDK\platform-tools directory.
>       at E:\MyProject3\platforms\android\cordova\lib\check_reqs.js:287:27
>       at _fulfilled (E:\MyProject3\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:854:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (E:\MyProject3\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:883:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (E:\MyProject3\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:13)
>       at E:\MyProject3\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:877:14
>       at runSingle (E:\MyProject3\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
>       at flush (E:\MyProject3\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:112:11)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:705:11)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:193:16) (node:10556) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:10556) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code. [00:59:17]  lint finished
>   in 4.12 s
>
> [OK] Your app has been deployed.
>        Did you know you can live-reload changes from your app with --livereload

I reinstalled Android studio and I reset path variable also then also this error is not going

i got this error when i try to convert ionic to apk